# Rendering a "sprite" in Away3D (molehill)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, render, away3d, molehill

Turns out, that I need to be able to render something similar to sprites, but having all of the goodness from Molehill.

Im new to Away3D and Molehill, and I was wondering how hard (if possible) would be to render a sprite (plain I guess) using Away3D, emulating somehow what Flash does with sprites, bitmaps, and the like.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to whip something up in Away3D, but if it's only 2D you need, it might be worth having a look at [M2D](http://www.flashrealtime.com/m2d/).

[image: M2D logo]

Comment: Mmmm seems like its not being continued ATM.

Comment: Starling Framework, ND2D and others are the popular ones out there ATM.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a normal sprite and draw a bitmap from it, and use that bitmap as material. You can then update the material whenever the sprite does. I build a text inputbox with blinking caret like that, looks quite dynamic! .. just remember every update of the material requires an upload of the bitmap to the GPU, which is quite heavy performance wise, so be sparse with the updates

Comment: Thanks for the post, but this is a really old question, I've beign using Starling for several months, problem solved :)